# I can view my web app even from a computer that is not part of my security group on my Ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am new to AWS so this may be a simple issue. I have a web app on an t2.micro instance. I have specific IPs assigned to a security network on my t2.micro instance. For some reason I can still view the web app from a machine that has an IP that is not part of the group.

What are some things that I should check? Is there a chance that I just need to wait an hour for the security group to be updated?

Comment: How do you "see" the webapp? IP:Port combination?
Check if the security group allows that port to be accessed from anywhere (IP section will have an entry like 0.0.0.0)

Comment: Can you share a print screen of your security group configuration, EC2, IP where you're accessing from, Etc?  While more info you share more help you'll receive.

Comment: There is no IP with the zeros, indicating anyone can access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some things to check:

- Is the SG actually associated with the instance?
- Remove all rules from the SG - that should prevent any access at all. Does it?

Security group updates are nearly instantaneous so there should be no need to wait for the change.

**UPDATE**: Also note, all devices on the network will have the same WAN (public) IP in the normal home networking environment. All traffic exits the network with the external IP assigned by your ISP.

If you are testing this in a home network, all the computers in the network will be able to access that service.

Comment: The SG is associated with the instance. Removing all groups prohibits all machines from viewing it. Thanks for letting me know that security group updates are nearly instantaneous. That helps.

Comment: Good news. Just add the rules back one at a time and confirm.

Comment: The problem is that when I add the IP of my work computer then every computer in my house can see the site. To be more clear, it is when I select the "My IP" option as opposed the the "Custom" option.

Comment: Ah.   All devices on the network will have the same WAN (public) IP in the normal home networking environment. All traffic exits the network with the external IP assigned by your ISP. That is what you are seeing.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. So when I go to work and my computer is on a different WAN then I will have to add that IP also? Also, I want the people at my work to see the site. When they go home and connect to their personal WIFI will I also need to add that IP?

Comment: Exactly right. If you are dealing with dynamic IPs it can get messy - lots of rule changes.  We try to mandate fixed/static ips for everyone in these cases.

Comment: @Alex note that there are quite a few test sites that will show you what your IP address appears to be, from the Internet.  You'll find that all your computers at home show the same address.  One such site that you might find useful is http://ipv4.icanhazip.com.